# Finding total character death count

Tags: dragon-age-origins

Is it possible to find out how many times a warden has died? If so, how? (Having to unpack or hex-dump save games is acceptable.)

Comment: Our Q&A format doesn't handle multiple questions per question very well, so I removed your second question. If you want to post a new question about how injury counts work, that's acceptable and preferable here. I did a cleanup of the question too - look it over to make sure it still asks what you mean to ask.